# Why is the article determined by the adjective and not the noun?

Tags: articles, sandhi

Please look at these phrases:

I think it is **a** dramatic scene.
I think it is **a** hilarious scene.
I think it is **an** intimate scene.
I think it is **an** ambiguous scene.

Why is the article determined by the adjective and not the noun?

Comment: The ***a / an*** choice has no direct connection to concepts like "adjective" and "noun" - it's purely a matter of whether the ***following word*** starts with a ***vowel sound*** (in ***speech***; the actual orthography is also irrelevant).

Comment: To a very high degree of accuracy, which is saying something for a rule in English, it's purely a speech aid. I wouldn't say absolute, because there exist examples of divided usage where people can't agree on the easiest way to pronounce say _a historian_ / _an historian_ (or have an idea that one style should be labelled incorrect). /// Thus, one writes 'He is an (extremely skilful) soccer player'. _And has to alter 'an' to 'a' if the parenthetical is dropped_! 'It is a[/an] N-phrase' depends on how one chooses to read the thing.